# Separate an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, null

So i have a buffer (array) :

```
char *buf;
buf = malloc(1024);
```

the buf is like `"foo\0bar\0foo\0bar\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..."`
it contains strings separated by the null terminator. I need to separate every string. I tried using the strtok() with \0 as the delemiter but of course it didnt work. How can i achieve that? Also afterwards each string needs to be "copied" somewhere else.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/tHOuHx)

Comment: so instead of using puts(p) can i use fputc of strcpy in order to cope the string found to another array?

Comment: You can use like `strcpy(aother_array[index], p);` (not `fputc`). In short, `p` can use the same usage as the result of `strtok`.

Comment: Oh thanks! I am going to try it out tomorrow and post the results :)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY using your piece of code i replaced puts with : `memcpy(list+size, p, strlen(p)); ` also added below that line the command ` size = strlen(p); ` thinking that if i dont add the +size, memcpy would overlap the previously written string. But the issue is that on the "list" the are copied only some of the strings. see here [link](http://ideone.com/iZLVzW)

Comment: What you want to do is unclear.. But probably `size = strlen(p);` --> `size += strlen(p);`, `memcpy(list+size, p, strlen(p));` --> `memcpy(list+size, p, strlen(p)+1);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY guess is should stop doing these amateur misakes :3
now its working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since what you have is not actually a string but a character array that may contain nulls, you can use the `memchr` function to search for nulls in the array.  Then you can use `strncpy` or `strcpy` to copy out the individual strings.

```
char *p = buf;
char *list[1024];
int cnt = 0;
while (p) {
    char *n = memchr(p, 0, 1024 - (p-buf));
    if (n) {
        list[cnt++] = strdup(p);
    } else {
        int size = 1024 - (p-buf);
        list[cnt] = malloc(size + 1);
        strncpy(list[cnt], p, size);
        list[cnt++][size] = 0;
    }
    p = n;
    if (p) p++;
}
```

We start by setting `p` to the beginning of `buf`.  Then on each iteration, we use `memchr` to look for the next null byte between `p` and the end of the array.  If we find one, we can treat `p` as a string and use `strdup` to allocate space for and duplicate the string.  If we don't find a null, we copy the remaining bytes to a newly allocated buffer and manually add a null byte.

Note that you'll need to know how large your buffer is so that you don't read past the end of it.

EDIT:

There was an issue with the code as originally written.  After one iteration, `p` was pointing to a null byte, so `memchr` would keep returning a pointer to that byte.  I added an increment past that byte at the end of the loop so it isn't checked again.

Comment: well the array is in that strict format. so it WILL contain nulls. could you please explain a bit more your code? i cant seem to get it to work right. the "copying" stops on the first null found. Also cnt seems to never increase(tried to print cnt after the loop and was 0).

Comment: @PantelosPapado See my edit.  I forget to increment `p` at the end of the loop.

Comment: i got it to work somehow :C. 
in the begining i do as follows:
`char *buf;
buf = malloc(1024);
memcpy(buf, data, sizeof data); //data is #defined `
but then when i try to fwrite the "list" i full of ureadable content :D
also tried using memcpy instead of strncpy

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the array and copy every character except the \0 into another array/struct depending on what that "somewhere else" needs to be. So every string would end at \0.